# Azure Function App 2.0 unable to deploy properly

Tags: azure, .net-core, deployment, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I'm trying to deploy my azure function (.NET Core 2.1) using zip based method but when I check the portal, Azure function always creates a sample run.csx to execute instead of executing my .cs file which contains run method tagged with function name.

Any ideas why is it unable to initialize the function after deployment?

I've tried:

1. Pushing my deployment zip while a timer trigger function app with the same name existing.
2. Deleting the above timer trigger function app then deploying the code.

In 1st case, previously existing run.csx is present in place of our function app.
In 2nd case, no function gets initialized.

Edit 1:

File structure:

|__TimerFunc/ [TimerFunc.cs, function.json]

|__project.csproj

|__host.json

Answer (score 0):

Only uploading the zip file is not enough, you must create the following App Setting:

```
WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE
```

and add the value

```
1
```

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package

Comment: Still the function is not present though the file structure is present.